# React, how do I update just one property in an object that uses the useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code I currently have a state like so:

```
const [caclulatorObj, setCalculatorObj] = useState({
  total: '0',
  next: null,
  operator: null
});

function clickHandler(isOperator, value) {
  setCalculatorObj(calculate(caclulatorObj, value));
}
```

The calculate function returns an object as described above. My question is do I always have to set a complete object when updating the state? For example, in my `calculate` function maybe I only update the `next` variable:

```
return {
  total: calculatorObj.total,
  next: someNewValue,
  operator: calculatorObj.operator
}
```

Can I just return this instead?:

```
return { next: someNewValue };
```

Or do I always need to return the full object?

Comment: You always need to set a new object.

Comment: @LuísRamalho is this different to non-hooks state that can also do partial updates?

Comment: You should not mutate the state directly, anytime you use the spread operator you're in essence creating a new object, even though you might be only updating a single prop.

Comment: Yep! The useState hook doesn't take care of partial updates for you. If you're storing an object in a useState hook you need to handle the merging yourself, or split each primitive value in your state into its own useState. This of course breaks down if you need to add keys dynamically, which is where useReducer comes in.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set the state like this:

```
function clickHandler(isOperator, key, value) {
  setCalculatorObj(calculate(caclulatorObj, { ...calculatorObj, [key]: value}));
}
```

And when you call it pass the key you want to modify:

```
onClick={(e) => clickHandler(false, 'next', e.target.value )}
```

Comment: What about if sometimes I return an object with two keys? Is that possible?

Comment: If you post the example code I'll see what you can do mate!